# Why can't i pass a UIScrollView for another class to scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm always trying to keep a clean UIViewController, and for that i'm passing responsibilities for ether classes to make.

When I'm Trying to pass my UIScrollView for another class to scroll it for me (its part from a larger method) It fails to work!

```
//Main UIViewController:
-(void)scrollToOffset
{
  //MainScrollVCModel has this class method that i call
     self.scrollView = [MainScrollVCModel tempScrollTo:self.scrollView];
}

//MainScrollVCModel:
+(UIScrollView *)tempScrollTo: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 300)];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
    return scrollView;
}
```

Why is this not working? What is the right way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: What is happening when you do this? - And why are you trying to use view animation on `setContentOffset:`? It is not an animatable view property, and is already animated.

Comment: And why are you not passing the desired offset into this method? You are always scrolling to the same point.

Comment: And why are you returning the scroll view from your class method and then just throwing it away?

Comment: Does the same code works when you run it inside the controller ?

Comment: This is just an example, I do not scroll to the same offset each time, and I'm passing the scroll view just because I tried   few different ways that didn't work out for me. @vdabury yes, the same code in the view controller does work.

Comment: It should work as far as I can see (and understand). But I've got a feeling that you shoudl not pass the scroll view for manipulation to another class. You should rather fetch the parameters from that other class, e.g. the offset to scroo, and peform the actuall scrolling in the view controller to which the scroll view belongs to. Thowever, it should work anyway. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: Just to be save: Are you on the main thread?

Comment: That's the question of an architecture. Seems to be an over-engineering.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks you! the problum us you said was not in this peace of code, but at the Allocation. I was doing in this method: +(void)setupScrollViewWithTap: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
             onViewController: (UIViewController *)vc And the UIScrollView actually never came back. So i changed it to:+(UIScrollView*)setupScrollViewWithTap: (UIScrollView *)scrollView
             onViewController: (UIViewController *)vc